# how to use ssl with smtp in c++

Tags: c++, ssl, smtp

im looking for code example or tutorial on what i need to do to code sending email 
via email client ( that i already have ) that will support ssl authentication 
i guess using open ssl

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and the [Sockets Library](http://www.alhem.net/Sockets/) both have SSL support. The latter has SMTP server class but unfortunately no client. I found an [example client](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1896) but it uses the simple C socket.h.

**Update:** Here are some real working examples. They all support SSL or TLS.

- [Msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net/): An SMTP client and SMTP plugin for mail user agents such as Mutt
- [sSMTP](ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/ssmtp/): Extremely simple MTA to get mail off the system to a Mailhub
- [libESMTP](http://www.stafford.uklinux.net/libesmtp/): lib that implements the client side of the SMTP protocol

Comment: hi,well i have no problem to implement simple smtp client .
but i don't know how to implement in code the combination of 
ssl/tls authentication that is "real code " this is what im looking for

Comment: no one knows how to implement simple smtp tls client example ?

Comment: I added some open source SMTP clients to my answer.

Comment: Are you going to re-implement or copy that from those places?  Plenty of libraries that do that which you can use (and update).